# Grails and Subdomains

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Does Grails know anything about sub-domains (i.e. subdomain.domain.com) ?   I don't see it discussed in the [manual](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html).   Is this purely an app server/web server issue?   Can be tied into grails controllers, either statically or dynamically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not matter which host is accessed for a java web application.

1. Supposing you have multiple clients separated on one host, e.g. customer1.yourhost.com, customer2.yourhost.com, etc. and all clients will have same functionalities.

   In the simplest case I propse, that you just use write a filter, which will always put some request variable, like this:

   ```
   def filters = {
       all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
           before = {
               if (request.serverName.contains(".")) {
                   def clientName = 
                     request.serverName.substring(0, request.serverName.indexOf("."))

                   request.currentClient = Client.findByClientName(clientName) // e.g.
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Then at any place you can check `request.currentClient` for the current accessed subdomain.

   However if it gets more complicated have a look at some multi-tenant plugins for grails.
2. If you want to have different functionalities for each subdomain e.g. help.yourhost.com and www.yourhost.com, I would propose that you write independent grails applications. You then setup a NGINX server to redirect those requests to the appropriate application running on your application server.

Comment: Thanks for breaking the problem out and showing various solutions.  Do you by chance have any thoughts regarding breaking up a subdomain for https, so that one has secure.mydomain.com in SSL mode?  Spring-security-core channel security (http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#17%20Channel%20Security) seems limited here.

Comment: So you have www.mydomain.com and want to switch over to secure.mydomain.com, when user logs in? I see the biggest issue with putting the cookie for the different host secure.mydomain.com. However though I haven't tried, but it is sufficient to configure spring security to redirect to an absolute URL by setting `grails.plugins.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl` to the proper value?

Comment: My current need is to make the site secure only during the product /service checkout, where I process credit cards.  After that processing is done, return to a non-SSL URL.  The way the site is currently designed, the user is logging in with his cart, just to see what discounts he gets.  From there, I go to SSL after he does a check out with his cart, and then when visa/mc processing is collected/done, return back to non-SSL.

Comment: I guess the best would be to open a new question for explicitly this use-case. I am not sure how to handle cookies on client side, when sub domain is switched. Sorry.

Comment: I'm employing this (code above) and am testing in dev mode / localhost -- do you know how one tests the above in dev mode?  Thanks

Comment: do some entries in yorhosts file like `127.0.0.1 asdf.localhost.de` `127.0.0.1 www.localhost.de`

Answer (score 1):

We run a few Grails apps on a single host using various sub domains. In all cases we use Apache to front the Tomcat server and use mod jk or forward proxy to handle the applications to the different Grails app. Most of it is rather straight forward, what we have not figured out is running the applications at the root level for the various domains, for instance -
http://app1.domain.com instead of http://app1.domain.com/app1

Comment: To configure as root context, you will need to change Config.groovy to use grails.app.context="/"

Answer (score 0):

The only place I'm aware of subdomains being considered is for tenant resolution when using the multi-tenant plugin. See http://tinyurl.com/6tuxwvs.