# Grails urlmappings: Different responses for subdomain and domain root "/" possible?

Tags: apache, grails, mod-rewrite, url-mapping

i'm working on a grails 2.2.3 application. This application has a backend, a marketing site and some userpages.

Each userpage should be available over username.domain.tld, the marketing site over domain.tld and www.domain.tld and the backend over domain.tld/backend OR backend.domain.tld.

I already implemented each of this parts but my problem is that i only have one URLMapping for "/". If i call the marketing site, i get the marketing view as response. If i call the username.domain.tld i also get the marketing site as response but i want that i get the /user/page as response. Using username.domain.tld/user/page i get the right response for the given user (i have a filter who checks the http header for the domain name and sets the subdomain name into params.username).

What do i have to do to get the userpages under "/" of the userpage subdomain working? Do i need to split my app into different apps (plugin architecture)? Should i do something like that? http://techsravi.blogspot.de/2011/05/managing-multiple-domain-and-sub-domain.html Or should i do some url-rewriting with Apache2?

What is the best and cleanest solution for my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails and Subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242527/grails-and-subdomains)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use Apache configuration with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to "redirect" some url to another within tomcat, mixing it with different VirtualHosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName username.domain.tld
    ProxyPass / http://mycomputer:8080/user
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mycomputer:8080/user
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ProxyPass / http://mycomputer:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mycomputer:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName backend.domain.tld
    ProxyPass / http://mycomputer:8080/backend
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mycomputer:8080/backend
</VirtualHost>
```

I haven't tested this exactly, but in other similar cases it works and we use it a lot here...

Comment: Hi Eylen, the problem is that the urls grails generates are always based on the configuration serverName and show the action and controller (i don't want). Is there a possibility to also change or modify each a-tag href attribute in html to the new subdomain based url? For example: In Grails i have domain.tld/page/username in the html content but in the browsers url field is written username.domain.tld. I want that the links in the html content are also changed because i need also clean links for google etc.

Comment: mmm, that's more difficult I think.  I suppose that you could manage it with Apache mod_rewrite or similar (but I'm not very good with it, just some copy and paste examples...) or, as you said, separate them in different grails applications each one with it's own name...

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a wrapper for the request with a java filter.

**Wapper**

https://gist.github.com/pablomoretti/2267314d3d6ffe000430

**Filter**

https://gist.github.com/pablomoretti/24238ef030b8906c9e88

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [Grails and Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242527/grails-and-subdomains) which may solve the problem you had.

It has solution for sub-domain which is required for you for each username. For this, it has used filter.

Another post http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/custom-theming-grails-applications/ has also similar solution which has used different approaches to solve their problems. And one of them is to use filter.